# Using `useLocation().search` in useEffect without infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out a way to use `query` inside of useEffect without an infinite loop.

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);

useEffect(() => {
  query.forEach((value, field) => {
    ...
  }
 }, [query]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: depends on what u r doing inside the loop

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial -- I'm doing a bit more processing, etc ```value.split(",").forEach((option) => { ... }```

Comment: @HenryWoody -- Like this ```const query = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search));```? I get `React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called inside a callback` -- I've been banging my head on this for a while now.

Comment: @n8tron moved to an answer to add more detail and clarity. Note that you can't call a hook (`useLocation`) within a callback so you'll have to separate that into its own line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `URLSearchParams` on every render (which is an object type and therefore has a different identity on each render), so the `useEffect` will run on every render (causing an infinite loop if the `useEffect` triggers a rerender).

Instead you can either move the definition of `query` into a `useMemo` call or just define `query` in the `useEffect` if it's not used elsewhere.

For example:

```
const { search } = useLocation();

const query = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);

useEffect(() => {
  query.forEach((value, field) => {
    ...
  }
 }, [query]);
```

or

```
const { search } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
  query.forEach((value, field) => {
    ...
  }
 }, [search]);
```